# C#/MYSql - How to insert csv data to mysql table

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, arrays, csv

I am trying to import data from csv file to MySQL table.The idea is to insert the data into MySQL with the data below.Any idea ?

My CSV file :

Car Name,Ferrari

Car Color,White

Year Manufactured,2005

Car Owners,Sam,Joel,Daniel,Marcos,George

I want to insert into database as below

Car Name , Car Color, Year Manufactured, Car Owners

Ferrari , White , 2005 , Sam

Ferrari , White , 2005 , Joel

Ferrari , White , 2005 , Daniel

Ferrari , White , 2005 , Marcos

Ferrari , White , 2005 , George

Comment: First of all if it's the same car, i.e. Ferrari white 2005, you should probably store the car owners in a separate table. Are there separate csv-files for cars or is the pattern of car, color, year and owners repeated in one file?

Comment: there is no seperated file.

Comment: Do you have any special requirement that calls for writing a program to do the import? There are many existing mysql client tools that can import csv data.